# Flutter: Sqflite firstintvalue returns null

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I have `rawQuery` which returns sum of a column, it returns correct value. But when I try to access that value using `Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);`, it returns `null`.

Here is my **code**:

```
String query = "SELECT SUM(pay.fees) FROM payments pay"; 

final results = await db.rawQuery(query);

print(Sqflite.firstIntValue(results));    //prints null

print(results);                           //prints [{SUM(pay.fees): 807650.0}]
```

There is one thing **strange** about this, we delivered this app last October and it was working absolutely fine till last week, it broke all of sudden. It took me several days to make my last working code compatible with latest flutter.

**Question:**

1. How can I fix this and get actual value?
2. Any clue why it broke all of sudden?

Comment: @pskink please help???

Comment: @Atlas_Gondal any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
String query = "SELECT SUM(pay.fees) as TOTAL FROM payments pay"; //create an alias

final results = await db.rawQuery(query);

print(results[0]['TOTAL']); //use alias to get results
```